# How to index specific elements only for a search filter JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my search filter script on a website; it is simple and works fine.

But if I would like to index specific elements only, what is the right way to do so?

Just for example, only `id="type"` and `id="taste"`, but not include `id="note"`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#filter").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("div.item-row").filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.item-row {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
p {
  line-height: 1.25em;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="filter"></input>
<div class="list-wrap">
  <div class="item-row">
    <p id="type">apple</p>
    <p id="taste">sweet</p>
    <p id="note">note: dummy text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-row">
    <p id="type">orange</p>
    <p id="taste">sour</p>
    <p id="note">note: dummy text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-row">
    <p id="type">pineapple</p>
    <p id="taste">sour</p>
    <p id="note">note: dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** When displaying the "filtered results", showing the complete `<div class="item-row">` is needed, like this:

`input` [ apple ]
___
| **apple**
| sweet
| note: dummy text
–––
| pine**apple**
| sour
| note: dummy text
–––

Comment: You must not have duplicate `id`s in your markup, as it creates invalid HTML. Use `class` instead.

Comment: @Anthony, you are not following the W3 standard about element *`id`* on a page. Check this: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use classes instead, as the `id` should be `unique`, then instead you `filter` the whole `item-row` group, you can `filter` on `type` and `teste` group, And hide `note` if there is a `value` in the `input`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#filter").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("div.item-row").filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($("> :not(.note)",this).text().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()));
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.item-row {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
p {
  line-height: 1.25em;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="filter"></input>
<div class="list-wrap">
  <div class="item-row">
    <p class="type">apple</p>
    <p class="taste">sweet</p>
    <p class="note">note: dummy text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-row">
    <p class="type">orange</p>
    <p class="taste">sour</p>
    <p class="note">note: dummy text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-row">
    <p class="type">pineapple</p>
    <p class="taste">sour</p>
    <p class="note">note: dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for did not mention in the question (edited). When displaying the "filtered results", showing the complete `<div class="item-row">` is needed.

Comment: But that already happens with your code.

Comment: with my script, it indexes everything inside each `class="item-row"`, including `<p class="note">note: dummy text</p>` which contain texts that will affect the filter experience~

Comment: Got it, thanks, I just update the answer, please check again.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

After OP edited their question I adjusted my script to fully address it:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#filter").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("div.item-row").filter(function () {
      $(this).toggle($("p:not(.note)",this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.item-row {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
p {
  line-height: 1.25em;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="filter"></input>
<div class="list-wrap">
  <div class="item-row">
    <p class="type">apple</p>
    <p class="taste">sweet</p>
    <p class="note">note: dummy text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-row">
    <p class="type">orange</p>
    <p class="taste">sour</p>
    <p class="note">note: dummy text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item-row">
    <p class="type">pineapple</p>
    <p class="taste">sour</p>
    <p class="note">note: dummy text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `$("div.item-row").filter(function () {...})` will go through all the`.item-row`divs and will either show or hide them depending on:
`$("p:not(.note)",this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1`. This expression collects the lowercase `.text()`s from all (but the `.note`) `<p>` elements in the current div (`this`) and looks for an occurence of the lowercase input string in it.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for did not mention in the question (edited). When displaying the "filtered results", showing the complete `<div class="item-row">` is needed.

Comment: Please check again, I updated my answer.